Identifying an old british thriller movie about nudes photographer
Does anybody know the name of an old UK psychological thriller where the main character is a nudes photographer which was molested by his father as a child (woken up with flashing lights...) ,who was a doctor of some sort (psychiatrist maybe), and filmed it for research. 
I remember a scene when his neighbour throws a party and then brings him a a cake, and he invites her in to show her his father films.She gets pretty scared by them. 
He rents flats in a big house which inherited.
The whole atmosphere is somewhat disturbing and dark.
The main actor somewhat resembles a young David Bowie.
It is an old film (60s,70s) but in colour.
The title is short and a bit obscene. Something like "The perv"

All I can think it might be is Peeping Tom, which matches the nude photographer & father backstory - I don't remember a cake, but that would fit the birthday event.
Plot synopsis from IMDB

Filmmaker and photographer Mark Lewis (Karl Heinz Böhm) spends days
  searching for just the right female models for his films which are
  studies of fear. He was raised by a psychologist father who used Mark
  as a subject for his own studies of fear and the exposure has left him
  marked psychologically so that he now is compelled to continue his
  search for women he murders for the camera as he films their
  reactions. Mark lives in the upper floors of his family house where he
  also has his photo lab and rents the downstairs to Helen Stephens
  (Anna Massey) and her blind mother Mrs. Stephens (Maxine Audley) whom
  he avoids until one day on Helen's birthday when the young nubile girl
  introduces herself to the photographer and they feel a connection.
  Mark trusts Helen enough to show her the films that his psychologist
  father took of him as a boy and the images disturb the girl but draws
  her closer to Mark. Mark's jobs as studio camera man for a film studio
  and cheesecake photographer for a local photo shop allows him easy
  access to women whom he murders while photographing to show their
  reactions to fear. When Helen accidentally sees some of his killing
  films she is appalled but wants to help Mark but the release of his
  secret is too much to bear as the police close in.

